# Css Expression not working in IE11

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, css-expressions

We developed a application with older Version of IE7.

And the code contains "CSS expression" but this not working in IE11.

Sample code :

```
div#GridViewContainer
        {
            position: relative !important;
            width: 1000px !important;
            overflow: auto !important;
        }
        _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .staticHeader
        {
            position: relative !important;
            top: expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
            z-index: 99 !important;
        }
        _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .StaticColumn
        {
            z-index: 90 !important;
            border: 1px solid gray !important;
            position: relative !important;
           left: expression(document.getElementById("GridViewContainer").scrollLeft);
        }
```

How to make work in IE11 and alternative way to do this?

How alter my code?

Comment: i want alternate solutions instead of "expression"

Comment: And i also  want to work in ie11 but not in older version (Ie7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **[You could do the same using pure JavaScript and get rid of CSS expressions all together.](http://robertnyman.com/2007/11/13/stop-using-poor-performance-css-expressions-use-javascript-instead/)**

**OR**

- **If you are feeling lazy or dont want to use JS, try setting the Document mode:**

  ```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
  ```

  add it to the `<head>...</head>` section.

  Note that this can possibly break the properties not supported by IE7 that you may have used.

---

**Why you should avoide using CSS Expressions:**

> Starting with Internet Explorer 11, CSS expressions are no longer
>   enabled for webpages loaded in the Internet zone. CSS expressions are
>   supported for pages loaded in other zones (such as the intranet zone)
>   when pages are rendered in IE7 standards mode or IE5 quirks mode.
>
> -[CSS expressions no longer supported for the Internet zone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn384050(v=vs.85).aspx)

Also,

> Unfortunately, the performance penalty imposed by CSS expressions is
>   considerable, as the browser reevaluates each expression whenever any
>   event is triggered, such as a window resize, a mouse movement and so
>   on. The poor performance of CSS expressions is one of the reasons they
>   are now deprecated in IE 8. If you have used CSS expressions in your
>   pages, you should make every effort to remove them and use other
>   methods to achieve the same functionality
>
> -[Page Speed: Avoid CSS expressions (deprecated)](http://gtmetrix.com/avoid-css-expressions-pagespeed.html)

Conditional Comments should somewhat work as suggested by *Leo Caseiroin* in his answer, it will actually save you some bandwidth on IE7+.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you split your file with your hacks and than, you can use Conditional comments for IE, like so:

```
<link href="css/ie11-without-hacks.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link href="css/ie7hacks.css" rel="stylesheet">
<![endif]-->
```

About conditional comments:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx